# Windows and Linux program with the same GUI and logic

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono

It's so many ways to create the programs for Windows and Linux, but I need something special.
1. My program should look same in Windows and Linux.
2. In windows version, the program uses .dll, in linux version the program uses .so
3. The program should implement the modern graphical interface (ideally designer provide me the psd or other format and I would can implement it in my program).

With Visual Studio and Mono I implemented the first two points, but the third point - it's hard to make.
WPF - is not implemented in Linux
Javascript - not so clear about how to work with .dll and .so files, running at some browser layer...

What technology can you suggest me to try?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For working with .dll and .so files in javascript, you should provide NPAPI/PPAPI/NACL interface for your .dll and .so files. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client for more details.

Comment: For cross-platform application, why not try `qt` or `wxwidgets`?

Comment: @gzh - thanks for your comment. as I wrote, I need good looking program :) With qt, wxwidgets I get the same to program written with c# and mono :)

Comment: @gzh - in addition, as I can see, to use the .dll or .so files I should recompile them with NaCl C compiler. It's impossible in my situation... :(

Comment: you can use [libqpsd](https://github.com/Code-ReaQtor/libqpsd) can handle psd in Qt, If you can not recompile you library, you can write a wrapper library to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that QT is the solution. You can try some javascript frameworks, but I think it's not ready yet for the serious desktop application.